# verb form of tiebreakers?

Tags: verbs

I wonder what's the verb form of tiebreakers.

E.g., I am tempted to say that: "I have a lot of options to solve this problem, and I use simplicity to break the ties between these choices."

Is this correct?

Comment: The default meaning of 'tiebreaker' is as in tennis, a quicker way to come to a result. How are you using the term?

Comment: It's not purely a tennis term. It's often used in other contexts where something has come to a deadlock at the end of a game, e.g. in golf or a quiz. So it's entirely fitting for distinguishing between two otherwise evenly matched competitors. Merriam-Webster says "an additional contest or period of play used to select a winner when a competition ends in a tie"

Comment: @Stuart F 'as in tennis', not 'in tennis'. The broadened usage (to choices in general) OP mentions is, I'd say, rare.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what's the verb form of tiebreakers.

In a general context, there isn't one. In a specific context (usually sporting) the verb is "break" and its object is "tie" - "Both players fought hard to break the tie." But "break" is used in its literal sense: you can also "break" a deadlock, a window, and a bank.

> E.g., I am tempted to say that: "I have a lot of options to solve this problem, and I use simplicity to break the ties between these choices."

Do not be tempted. This is so unidiomatic that it is wrong. Your first problem is that there is no indicated equality among the options to show that there was a tie in the first place.

> Is this correct?

No.

"and I use the test/criterion/level of simplicity to decide which one to take." (This is formal).

Comment: I disagree. In the US at least, where sports rule all ;) , “break ties” is used. For example: https://www.nfl.com/standings/tie-breaking-procedures

Comment: I agree with @Damila. In the U.S. at least, we often talk about "breaking a tie" or "breaking ties". Google provides many examples from reputable sources.

Answer (score 0):

*Tip the scales* is commonly used with this meaning.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tip-the-balance-scales)

> tip the balance/scales (also tilt the balance)
>
> If something tips the balance or tips the scales, it is the thing that
> causes a particular situation to happen or a particular decision to be
> made, when other situations or decisions are possible:
>
> *The teams were evenly matched until two quick goals from Rooney tipped the balance in favour of England.*
>
> *She was a good candidate, but her lack of computer skills tipped the
> scales against her.*

In the example sentence,

> I have a lot of options to solve this problem, and what tips the scales for me is simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Break ties is used in American English, in sports at least. For example, a description of how the NFL will determine which team gets into the playoffs or gets a certain rank in the playoffs amongst teams with the same win-loss record:

> [NFL Tiebreaking Procedures](https://www.nfl.com/standings/tie-breaking-procedures)

> The following procedures will be used to break standings ties for postseason playoffs and to determine regular-season schedules.

Answer (score -2):

*Break the ties* is fine, although it’s often used in sports contests where there are only two opponents; thus, *break the tie.*

I’d recast, and say “I use simplicity to choose between them.”